# SOAPUI Groovy - Update XML request in another test case

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am having 2 test cases in my suite. 
First test case contains 1 test step with xml request. 
Second test case contains 1 test step with groovy script. I want to run the 1st test case from this groovy script a number of times. Every time I want to change the input XML. I am unable to update the input XML in TestCase 1.
I have the following the code for the groovy script:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context);
def tsuite = testRunner.testCase.testSuite
def acctInq_tstepName = tsuite.getTestCaseAt(1).getTestStepAt(0).getName()
def acctInq_requestHolder = tsuite.getTestCaseAt(1).testSteps[acctInq_tstepName].testRequest.getRequestContent()
def acctInq_req = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("$acctInq_requestHolder")
acctInq_req["//soapenv:Envelope[1]/soapenv:Body[1]/v2:AcctInqRq[1]/ifx:DepAcctId[1]/ifx:AcctId[1]"] = "0009917812344"
acctInq_req.updateProperty()
```

I also tried using

```
tstep.setPropertyValue("request",cStr(acctInq_req))
```

In either case the XML is not getting updated. Please help.

Comment: Please let us know what you expected to happen and what actually happened.  Specific information such as actual output can be very useful as the community tries to help you.

Comment: I am expecting the original request xml to get updated so that I can run the test step with new xml. But the xml is not getting updated.

Comment: If you can provide the initial XML and the fields that you want to update, I will try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try set node value like below and check if it fixed the issue:

```
acctInq_req.setNodeValue("//*:ifx:AcctId[1]", "0009917812344")
```